# Transition Doesn't Work with Multiple Attributes

Tags: css, transition

I have a div with relative position and left, top, and box-shadow defined. When I write a div:hover statement, I am trying to transition each of these attributes. It works with individual attributes, but not with 2 or more. Is this supposed to happend and/or how do I fix it such that multiple transitions can occur.

I solved the problem of top and left not being defined before hover, but it still doesn't solve the problem when there are multiple transitions at once.

```
.faq-card {
                border-radius: 10px;
                border: 1px solid white;
                box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px rgba(216, 44, 44, .5);
                height: 100px;
                position: relative;
                left: 0px;
                top: 0px;
}
.faq-card:hover {
                box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(216, 44, 44, .5);
                left: 10px;
                top: 10px;
                transition: left 1000ms ease;
                transition: top 1000ms ease;
                transition: box-shadow 1000ms ease;
}
```

I expect div to move 10px to the right, 10px down, and the box shadow to fade into the div in a transition manner rather than jerky. However, they all do this at once with no transition. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do is all

```
transition: all 1000ms ease;
```

It will take affect on all changes

Comment: Yea this worked and now I feel dumb lol. I will accept it in 10 minutes when it lets me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This because each [**`transition`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) property is overriding the previous ones.

If you need to transition *multiple* properties you can either use `all` (which may lead to unexpected transitions you did not intend) or **comma-separate** the values to be changed

So instead of:

```
            transition: left 1000ms ease;
            transition: top 1000ms ease;
            transition: box-shadow 1000ms ease;
```

use

```
            transition: left 1000ms ease, top 1000ms ease, box-shadow 1000ms ease;
```

Note that in this way you can have **different times and easing functions** for EACH property in one statement.